# MS Access 2007 subform reload on formheader = visible?

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm getting strange behavior in Access 2007 on a form designed in Access 2003.

I have an unbound main form with a data-bound subform. Within the Form_load of the main form, I set the subform sourceobject, which loads the subform recordset, etc. After the subform loads, but still within the Form_load of the main form, I set `Me.FormHeader.Visible = True`. After this line runs, for some reason the subform seems to close and reopen -- its Form_Unload fires, and it runs through its load process again.

Any idea why this would be happening? It's annoying, because its recordset is based on a parameter query, and the parameters get zapped when it reloads so it ends up prompting users for parameters.

Comment: I've gotten around it for the moment by doing the `Me.FormHeader.Visible = True` (and other main form display settings) *before* setting the subform sourceobject. But I still would like to know why setting a property on the main form causes the subform to reload, it makes no sense to me.

Comment: I'm not sure about your exact situation, but with a subform bound to a bound parent form, the OnCurrent event of the child form first twice. Maybe there's a relationship with the problem you're encountering?

Comment: Thanks, but my parent form is unbound so not exactly my situation.

Comment: My point was that it could be happening with your situation, too. Have you investigated how often the child form's OnCurrent event is firing?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to live with (and work around) the behavior of MS Access, no matter how strange or annoying it is.

In this case I would probably advise that you move away from a parameter query and instead prompt the user for their input using VBA, store their input in a form level variable, and use that input to set the recordsource during the subform's Form_Load event. This way the user will only be prompted one time and never need to know that the form actually loaded twice.

Comment: Thanks. I have done similar things in the past. But I've found that parameter queries + events (i.e. subform responds to a notify() event from the parent, or vice-versa, when the query params are updated) really works best for me. Not using parameter queries means you build the SQL string yourself, which is (1) slower to run and (2) runs the potential risk of SQL injection.

Comment: Also building the SQL string is a pain in the a** since you have to escape quote characters and serialize non-string data types in the right format for Jet SQL to understand, etc.

Comment: How is that any different from building a SQL string for any database engine there is?

Comment: I think manually building an SQL string is bad practice whatever the database engine. But if you have to do it, it would be nice if your framework did the escaping/serializing for you instead of everyone having to roll their own.